# Javascript alert sum of substrings found with for()

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, substring

I am trying to count the amount of 'a' letters in a variable, and something is not working:

The js code is :

```
function verChars() {
    var z = document.getElementById("num").value;
    var y = 0;
    var x = 0;

    for (x = 0; x < z.length; x++) {
        if (z.substring(x) === "a") {
            y++;
        }
    }

    if (y === 0) {
        alert("The string has no 'a' char.");   
    } else if (y === 1) {
        alert("The string has a single 'a' char."); 
    } else {
        alert("The string has "+ y +" 'a' chars."); 
    }
}
```

And the HTML code is:

```
<input type="text" id="num" value="Some text...">
<input type="button" onClick="verChars();" value="Test!">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `z.substring(x)`, simply do `z[x]==='a'`

structure of substring is

```
string.substring(from, to)
```

so when you just pass `from` argument, it takes part of the string after `that many` characters

i.e. `"hello".substring(3) =="lo"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `z.charAt(x)`, or `z[x]`.

Or using a regular expression:

```
y = z.replace(/[^a]/g, '').length;
```

That replacement process results in a string consisting of everything in the original that's *not* an "a", and then it just grabs the length of what's left.  (The original string is left intact by `.replace()`.)

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong method. Instead of `.substring()` use `.charAt()`.

```
if (z.charAt(x) === "a") { ... }
```

However, there are several other short approaches to count letters in the string, e.g.

```
var y = z.split("a").length - 1;
// or
var y = (z.match(/a/g) || []).length;
```

Comment: Neat! Worked perfectly! Thank you both!
But why wouldn't the .substring work?

Comment: Because [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) *returns a **subset** of a string between one index and another, or through the end of the string*, and not the certain character.